# StackOverFlowError when trying to use action bar from support library

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu, stack-overflow, android-actionbaractivity

I have a very annoying problem, I was testing on Samsung (s3) device and every thing was working just fine, then I used LG device with OS 4.0 and When I try to open my application I got stackoverflowerror in the following method

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actions_menu, menu);   
}
```

My base activity extending **ActionBarActivity** from **android.support.v7**

can any one help please ?

**EDIT 1**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actions_menu, menu);

    MenuItem editItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_edit);
    MenuItem saveItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_save);
    MenuItem deleteItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_delete);

    editItem.setVisible(isEditEnable());
    saveItem.setVisible(isSaveEnable());
    deleteItem.setVisible(isDeleteEnable());

    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    return true;
}
```

the exception occurred in **getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actions_menu, menu);**

Comment: can you post your full onCreateOptionsMenu code ?

Comment: @JafarKhQ : I have edit the question with the full implementation of onCreateOptionsMenu()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you calling `return onCreateOptionsMenu();` after inflation the menu.
instead just use `return true;`

**update:**
You're calling `invalidateOptionsMenu();` which i think will call `onCreateOptionsMenu()` again.
Remove it and change your menu in `onPrepareOptionMenu()`, there is no need to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`